# Calculating a function repetitively without using a For loop

Tags: functions, matrix, recursion, list-manipulation

In my programme I have defined all these functions:

```
getA[kappa_] := 
  Table[2*Cos[(2*Pi/n)*(Abs[j - i])*kappa], {i, n}, {j, n}];
getF[csi_, a_, b_] := 
  Module[{csiInv = Inverse[csi]}, .5 Tr[csiInv.a.csiInv.b]];
getG[csi_, f_, a_] := Module[{csiInv = Inverse[csi]}, 
   csiInv.a.csiInv/2];
getE[g_, k_] := 
  Module[{kinv = Inverse[k], ktransinv2 = Transpose[kinv]},
   ktransinv2.g.kinv];
getW[k_, a_, e_] := Module[{ktrans = Transpose[k]},
   Tr[k.a.ktrans.e]];
getV[csi_, e_, e2_, k_] := 
  Module[{ktrans = Transpose[k], e2trans = Transpose[e2]},
   2*Tr[csi.ktrans.e.k.csi.ktrans.e2trans.k]];
getP[g_, delta_] := Module[{deltatranspose = Transpose[delta, {1}]},
   deltatranspose.g.delta];
```

Now I need to use them for different values of the variable `kappa`, ranging from 1 to `n`. Even if the passages of the different calculations performed are a bit complicated to follow, the crucial point is that whenever `kappa` changes, not only `getA`, but also all the other functions, change. What I am really interested in is the values of the `getW` and `getP` functions. For every value of `kappa` from 1 to `n`, I should be able to store the values of `getW` and `getP` into two different "arrays" (actually, a matrix in the case of `getW` and a proper array in the case of `getP`). How can I do that, without using a `For` loop?

EDIT:

I am including the full code, where I specify what all the elements are, and I try to implement the suggestions received in the comments:

```
getA[kappa_] := 
  Table[2*Cos[(2*Pi/n)*(Abs[j - i])*kappa], {i, n}, {j, n}];
getF[csi_, a_, b_] := 
  Module[{csiInv = Inverse[csi]}, .5 Tr[csiInv.a.csiInv.b]];
getG[csi_, f_, a_] := Module[{csiInv = Inverse[csi]}, 
   csiInv.a.csiInv/2];
getE[g_, k_] := Module[{kinv = Inverse[k]},
   Transpose[kinv].g.kinv];
getW[k_, a_, e_] := Module[{ktrans = Transpose[k]},
   Tr[k.a.ktrans.e]];
getV[csi_, e_, e2_, k_] := 
  Module[{ktrans = Transpose[k], e2trans = Transpose[e2]},
   2*Tr[csi.ktrans.e.k.csi.ktrans.e2trans.k]];
getP[g_, delta_] := Module[{deltatranspose = Transpose[delta, {1}]},
   deltatranspose.g.delta];

n = L = 4;
sigma = 3;
nyquist = n/2 + 1;
sampling = 8;
mu = 0.0;

powerspectrum[i_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, i == 0}, {Exp[-(2*Pi*i*sigma/L)^2], 
     0 < i <= n/2}, {Exp[-(2*Pi*(n - i)*sigma/L)^2], n/2 < i <= n}}];
pts = Table[powerspectrum[i], {i, 0, n}] ;

inverse = InverseFourier[pts];

func[inverse_] := 
  Module[{n = Length[inverse], tup}, 
   tup = Cases[
     Tuples[Range[n], 2], {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] < (n - 1)/2];
   SparseArray[
    Thread[tup -> (inverse[[Abs[#1 - #2] + 1]] & @@@ tup)], {n, n}]];
CSI = func[inverse];

Kmatrix = 
  Table[((3.0*70.0*70.0*0.3)/(2.0*300000.0*300000.0))*((j + 1)*(i + 
        2 - (j + 1)))*(1.0 + (70.0/300000.0)*(j + 1)), {i, 0, 
    n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];

leftREAL = 
  Table[RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[mu, Exp[-(2*Pi*k*sigma/L)^2]]], {k, n/2}];
rightREAL = Reverse[leftREAL] /. {x_, y_} -> {n - x, y};
fullREAL = Join[{0.0}, Most[leftREAL], rightREAL];

leftIMAGINARY = 
  Table[RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[mu, Exp[-(2*Pi*k*sigma/L)^2]]], {k, n/2 - 1}];
rightIMAGINARY = -Reverse[leftIMAGINARY] /. {x_, y_} -> {n - x, y};
fullIMAGINARY = Join[{0.0}, leftIMAGINARY, {0.0}, rightIMAGINARY];

fullfield = fullREAL + I*fullIMAGINARY;

fieldconfiguration = InverseFourier[fullfield];

Wab = Table[
   getE[getG[CSI, getF[CSI, getA[alpha], getA[beta]], getA[alpha], 
     Kmatrix]], {alpha, n}, {beta, n}] // MatrixForm
Pa = Table[
   getP[getG[CSI, getA[alpha], getA[alpha]], 
    fieldconfiguration], {alpha, n}] // MatrixForm
```

I am now getting the following problem:

```
Dot::dotsh: Tensors {{1.39036 +0.225877 I,0.046518 -0.874121 I,-0.573392+0.0884825 I,0.046518 +0.30145 I,0.272321 -0.137394 I},<<3>>,{0.272321 -0.137394 I,0.046518 +0.30145 I,-0.573392+0.0884825 I,0.046518 -0.874121 I,1.39036 +0.225877 I}} and {{2,0,-2,0},{0,2,0,-2},{-2,0,2,0},{0,-2,0,2}} have incompatible shapes.
```

which means that I am multiplying matrices or arrays that have not got the same dimension, but I cannot see where I am making this mistake. Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: How are they related? How do the other functions change when `kappa` changes?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer every time that you see an 'a' matrix in the definition of the functions, that is a matrix obtained through the geta[kappa_definition]. So, this creates a chain: if I change 'kappa', then 'a' changes and so on...

Comment: Ok, let's take `getW` for instance. What is the first argument `k`? The second argument is `getA[kappa]`, and the third is `getE[getG[csi,getF[csi,getA[kappa],b],getA[kappa],k]` What is `csi`, and what is `b`? If you have all these, and you want a table of all `kappa`-values from 1 to `n`, simply use `Table`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer yes I think you are right, nevertheless if I try with the following:

Comment: Wab = Table[
   getE[getG[CSI, getF[CSI, getA[alpha], getA[beta]], getA[alpha], 
     k]], {alpha, n}, {beta, n}] // MatrixForm
Pa = Table[
   getP[getG[CSI, getA[alpha], getA[alpha]], 
    fieldconfiguration], {alpha, n}] // MatrixForm

Comment: I get a result which is basically composed of matrices that are not completely filled with numbers...sometimes they have words, like "Inverse[CSI]", as if Mathematica was not able to actually give a meaning to those expressions...what I have done wrong?

Comment: You have not told Mathematica what `CSI` and `n` are.

Comment: In my edit you can see what the CSI matrix is and the size n too. Now the problem seems due to a multiplication between matrices with different sizes

Comment: `CSI` is 5x5 and `getA[1]` is 4x4 so the dot product in `getF` fails

Comment: Thanks @SimonWoods! I hadn't realised that! But how can I make CSI 4x4 (as it should be)?

Comment: Just trace it back through the code - `CSI` is 5x5 because `inverse` is length 5. `inverse` is length 5 because `pts` is length 5. Maybe the table should run from 0 to n-1 instead of 0 to n? I haven't tried to understand what you're doing so I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `kappa` values ahead of time (eg. `{1,2,3,4,5}` ) and the dimension of your `getA` matrix is 3, for example

```
kappa = Range[5];
n=3;
```

then use a [`Pure Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) it to the [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) of `kappa` values

```
getA[#] & /@ kappa
getW[IdentityMatrix[3], getA[#], IdentityMatrix[3]] & /@ kappa
```

> {
>      {{2, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, -1}, {-1, -1, 2}},
>      {{2, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, -1}, {-1, -1, 2}},
>      {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2,  2}},
>      {{2, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, -1}, {-1, -1, 2}},
>      {{2, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, -1}, {-1, -1, 2}}
>     }
>
> {6, 6, 6, 6, 6}

If you want this to happen dynamically, you'll have to use a different approach, but given your mention of a procedural `For` loop, I suspect that's not your intention.